# Nested If Statement Not displaying Correctly

Tags: java

I am creating Payroll systems for a side project. I am using the nested if statement to see what billing schedule the user selected (52 or 26) then calculate gross pay, taxes and other deductions. The 52 week pay schedule works correctly but the 26 week pay schedule does not display any values.

```
double hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(txtHoursWorked.getText());
    double hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(txtHourlyPay.getText());
    double overtimeHours = Double.parseDouble(txtOvertimeHours.getText());
    double overtimeRate = Double.parseDouble(txtOvertimePay.getText());

    // Declare variables
    double basicPay;
    double overtimePay;
    double grossPay;

    double taxes;
    double yearlyCompensation;
    double cpp;
    double ei;
    double deductions;
    double netPay;


    if (cmbPayPeriod.getSelectedItem().equals("52 Week Pay Period")) {

        grossPay = basicPay + overtimePay;
        txtGrossPay.setText(x.format(grossPay));

        yearlyCompensation = grossPay * 52;

        if (yearlyCompensation < 45282) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.15) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            netPay = grossPay - deductions;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));   
            txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));

        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 90536) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.205) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            netPay = grossPay - deductions;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions)); 
            txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));
        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 140388) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.265) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            netPay = grossPay - deductions;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));  
            txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));
        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 200000) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.29) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            netPay = grossPay - deductions;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions)); 
            txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));
        }

        else {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.33) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            netPay = grossPay - deductions;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));  
            txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));
        }


    if (cmbPayPeriod.getSelectedItem().equals("n")) {

        grossPay = (basicPay + overtimePay) * 2;
        txtGrossPay.setText(x.format(grossPay));

        yearlyCompensation = grossPay * 26;

        if (yearlyCompensation < 45282) {


            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.15) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));     

        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 90536) {


            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.205) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));  
        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 140388) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.265) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));  

        }

        else if (yearlyCompensation < 200000) {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.29) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));  
        }

        else {

            taxes = (yearlyCompensation * 0.33) / 52;
            cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
            ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;

            deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;

            txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
            txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
            txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
            txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions)); 


        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: No one wants to read 200 lines of code. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: What happened when you walked through the code with a debugger?

Comment: are you sure this test is what you want `if (cmbPayPeriod.getSelectedItem().equals("n"))` ?

Comment: When I use the debugger it does not recognize '26 week pay period'.

Comment: I already tested with n, it does not seem to recognize my statement.

Comment: Not sure because of the indentation, but it seems that you check for "n" only if the check for "52 Week Pay Period" is true - but the selected item can't be both at the same time

Comment: That makes sense, how can I change my code to avoid that problem?

Comment: You should close the block after the first `if (cmbPayPeriod...) {` with `}` before the second `if (cmbPayPeriod...) {` (and then you will need to remove one of the trailing `}` so that your code compiles again)

Comment: When I try to close the block on the first if statement, it gives me an error 'cannot find symbol'. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains many duplications and that makes it hard read and hard to debug.

Essentially it breaks down into six parts:

- parsing input

  ```
  double hoursWorked = Double.parseDouble(txtHoursWorked.getText());
  double hourlyRate = Double.parseDouble(txtHourlyPay.getText());
  double overtimeHours = Double.parseDouble(txtOvertimeHours.getText());
  double overtimeRate = Double.parseDouble(txtOvertimePay.getText());
  ```
- pay calculation, not actually in the code that you have shown

  ```
  double basicPay = hoursWorked * hourlyRate;
  double overtimePay = overtimeHours * overtimeRate;
  ```
- gross pay calculation, depending on schedule

  ```
  double grossPay;
  double yearlyCompensation;
  if (cmbPayPeriod.getSelectedItem().equals("52 Week Pay Period")) {
      grossPay = basicPay + overtimePay;
      yearlyCompensation = grossPay * 52;
  } else if (cmbPayPeriod.getSelectedItem().equals("n")) {
      grossPay = (basicPay + overtimePay) * 2;
      yearlyCompensation = grossPay * 26;
  } else {
      //this must be an error
      //just bail out:
      return;
  }
  ```

(Your current code does not show what will be done if the user selects neither "52 Week Pay Period" nor "n" - my code handles this as an error an aborts the calculation. You might need to do something else.)

- determine tax rate

  ```
  double taxRate;
  if (yearlyCompensation < 45282) {
      taxRate = 0.15;
  } else if (yearlyCompensation < 90536) {
      taxRate = 0.205;
  } else if (yearlyCompensation < 140388) {
      taxRate = 0.265;
  } else if (yearlyCompensation < 200000) {
      taxRate = 0.29;
  } else {
      taxRate = 0.33;
  }
  ```
- calculate taxes and net pay

  ```
  double taxes = (yearlyCompensation * taxRate) / 52;
  double cpp = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0495) / 52;
  double ei = (yearlyCompensation * 0.0163) / 52;
  double deductions = taxes + cpp + ei;
  double netPay = grossPay - deductions;
  ```
- show results

  ```
  txtGrossPay.setText(x.format(grossPay));
  txtTaxP.setText(x.format(taxes));
  txtCPP.setText(x.format(cpp));
  txtEI.setText(x.format(ei));
  txtDeductions.setText(x.format(deductions));
  txtNetPay.setText(x.format(netPay));
  ```

Since the parts are now much smaller it will be much easier to find problems like wrongly nested conditions.